# How to create and transfer files from desktop to remote server?

Tags: server, remote, filezilla

Currently trying to convert a folder on my desktop to transfer over to a remote server so I can run Banjo Bayesian network software. Been attempting to do so using filazilla but unsuccessful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you [compress that folder into a tar archive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46971/85039) and then use the `rsync` command to transfer that file like this:

`rsync /path/to/local/file.tar  username@remote.server.com:folder`